# How to schedule intent service correctly in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I'm working on app in which I want to schedule service in a interval of 6 hours. I'm calling this method from main activity. When this activity open then it call this method and hits the service. I don't want to execute it whenever this method executes. After first exceution of this service it should execute after 6 hours or so not app open. Is there any flag or something I need to do set to do that.

```
public static void scheduleHeartBeat(Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, HearBeatService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() , 6*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
}


public class HearBeatService extends IntentService {

    public HearBeatService() {
        super("HearBeatService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("HeartBeat", "Hey Testing!!!");
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .....
    scheduleHeartBeat(this);

    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use SharedPrefereces. Store alarm status in SharedPreferences with a key(set true once alarm is initiated). and according to alarmStatus call that method.

Comment: According to the @bharat's suggestion, you can check: `if(mSharedPreferencesAlarmStatus == false){ // set the alarm and save true value }`

Answer (score 0):

User broadcastreceiver.

1. Create class that extends Intent service class
2. Create class that broadcastreceiver class and call the Intent service (from step1)
3. Create pending intent for the broadcastreciever(from step2)
4. Register the pending intent with alarm manager of 6 hours delay

Dont Forget to register your service and receiver in the android manifest.